# Drawing graphs and Feynman diagrams with axodraw

Tags: diagrams, dvips

I used CalcHEP to get following graph. However, the output gives a problem and it does not draw any graphs. (I have install `axodraw.sty` locally). The code is as follows:

```
    % u, D -> W+, b, B
\documentstyle[axodraw]{article}
\begin{document}
{
\unitlength=1.0 pt
\SetScale{1.0}
\SetWidth{0.7}      % line    size control
\normalsize    %  letter  size control
\begin{picture}(300,200)(0,0)
\Text(171.0,199.4)[t]{$u, D -> W+, b, B$}
% ====================   X-axis =============
\LinAxis(50.73,38.83)(291.23,38.83)(2.500,2,-4,-0.000,1.5)
\Text(50.7,32.4)[t]{$0.0$}
\Text(147.2,32.4)[t]{$200$}
\Text(243.0,32.4)[t]{$400$}
\Text(291.2,22.7)[rt]{$M(b,B)$}
% ====================   Y-axis =============
\LinAxis(50.73,38.83)(50.73,176.05)(3.302,3,4,-0.000,1.5)
\Text(43.8,38.8)[r]{$0.0$}
\Text(43.8,80.3)[r]{$3E-4$}
\Text(43.8,121.7)[r]{$6E-4$}
\Text(43.8,163.8)[r]{$9E-4$}
\rText(18.2,176.1)[tr][l]{Diff. cross section [pb/GeV]}
% ============== end of axis ============
\Line(54.5,47.2)(55.1,47.2) 
\Line(55.1,46.6)(55.1,47.9) 
\Line(55.1,78.3)(55.7,78.3) 
\Line(55.7,75.7)(55.7,80.9) 
\Line(55.7,77.0)(57.0,77.0) 
\Line(56.4,75.7)(56.4,79.0) 
\Line(57.0,73.8)(57.6,73.8) 
\Line(57.0,72.5)(57.0,75.7) 
\Line(57.6,75.1)(58.2,75.1) 
\Line(58.2,73.1)(58.2,77.0) 
\Line(58.2,68.6)(59.5,68.6) 
\Line(58.9,66.7)(58.9,69.9) 
\Line(59.5,69.9)(60.1,69.9) 
\Line(59.5,68.0)(59.5,71.8) 
\Line(60.1,62.8)(60.8,62.8) 
\Line(60.8,61.5)(60.8,64.1) 
\Line(60.8,61.5)(61.4,61.5) 
\Line(61.4,60.2)(61.4,63.4) 
\Line(61.4,59.5)(62.6,59.5) 
\Line(62.0,58.9)(62.0,60.8) 
\Line(62.6,60.8)(63.3,60.8) 
\Line(62.6,59.5)(62.6,62.1) 
\Line(63.3,58.9)(63.9,58.9) 
\Line(63.9,57.6)(63.9,60.2) 
\Line(63.9,53.7)(65.1,53.7) 
\Line(64.5,53.1)(64.5,55.0) 
\Line(65.1,58.3)(65.8,58.3) 
\Line(65.1,57.0)(65.1,60.2) 
\Line(65.8,54.4)(66.4,54.4) 
\Line(65.8,53.1)(65.8,55.7) 
\Line(66.4,53.1)(67.0,53.1) 
\Line(67.0,52.4)(67.0,54.4) 
\Line(67.0,53.7)(68.3,53.7) 
\Line(67.6,52.4)(67.6,54.4) 
\Line(68.3,52.4)(68.9,52.4) 
\Line(68.3,51.1)(68.3,53.1) 
\Line(68.9,51.8)(69.5,51.8) 
\Line(69.5,51.1)(69.5,53.1) 
\Line(69.5,53.1)(70.8,53.1) 
\Line(70.1,51.8)(70.1,53.7) 
\Line(70.8,51.8)(71.4,51.8) 
\Line(70.8,51.1)(70.8,53.1) 
\Line(71.4,49.8)(72.0,49.8) 
\Line(71.4,49.2)(71.4,51.1) 
\Line(72.0,52.4)(72.7,52.4) 
\Line(72.7,51.1)(72.7,53.1) 
\Line(72.7,48.5)(73.9,48.5) 
\Line(73.3,47.9)(73.3,49.2) 
\Line(73.9,49.2)(74.5,49.2) 
\Line(73.9,48.5)(73.9,49.8) 
\Line(74.5,49.2)(75.2,49.2) 
\Line(75.2,47.9)(75.2,49.8) 
\Line(75.2,48.5)(75.8,48.5) 
\Line(75.8,47.2)(75.8,49.2) 
\Line(75.8,50.5)(77.0,50.5) 
\Line(76.4,49.2)(76.4,51.1) 
\Line(77.0,48.5)(77.7,48.5) 
\Line(77.0,47.9)(77.0,49.2) 
\Line(77.7,48.5)(78.3,48.5) 
\Line(78.3,47.2)(78.3,49.2) 
\Line(78.3,46.0)(79.5,46.0) 
\Line(78.9,45.3)(78.9,46.6) 
\Line(79.5,47.9)(80.2,47.9) 
\Line(79.5,47.2)(79.5,48.5) 
\Line(80.2,48.5)(80.8,48.5) 
\Line(80.8,47.2)(80.8,49.2) 
\Line(80.8,46.0)(81.4,46.0) 
\Line(81.4,45.3)(81.4,46.6) 
\Line(81.4,46.6)(82.7,46.6) 
\Line(82.0,46.0)(82.0,47.2) 
\Line(82.7,47.9)(83.3,47.9) 
\Line(82.7,47.2)(82.7,48.5) 
\Line(83.3,46.0)(83.9,46.0) 
\Line(83.9,45.3)(83.9,46.6) 
\Line(83.9,46.6)(85.2,46.6) 
\Line(84.6,46.0)(84.6,47.2) 
\Line(85.2,44.0)(85.8,44.0) 
\Line(85.2,44.0)(85.2,44.7) 
\Line(85.8,46.0)(86.4,46.0) 
\Line(85.8,45.3)(85.8,46.6) 
\Line(86.4,46.6)(87.1,46.6) 
\Line(87.1,46.0)(87.1,47.2) 
\Line(87.1,46.6)(88.3,46.6) 
\Line(87.7,46.0)(87.7,47.2) 
\Line(88.3,47.2)(88.9,47.2) 
\Line(88.3,46.6)(88.3,47.9) 
\Line(88.9,46.6)(89.6,46.6) 
\Line(89.6,46.0)(89.6,47.2) 
\Line(89.6,47.9)(90.8,47.9) 
\Line(90.2,47.2)(90.2,48.5) 
\Line(90.8,50.5)(91.4,50.5) 
\Line(90.8,49.8)(90.8,51.1) 
\Line(91.4,51.8)(92.1,51.8) 
\Line(91.4,50.5)(91.4,52.4) 
\Line(92.1,61.5)(92.7,61.5) 
\Line(92.7,59.5)(92.7,62.8) 
\Line(92.7,86.7)(93.9,86.7) 
\Line(93.3,84.8)(93.3,89.3) 
\Line(93.9,172.8)(94.6,172.8) 
\Line(93.9,168.9)(93.9,176.1) 
\Line(94.6,118.4)(95.2,118.4) 
\Line(95.2,115.2)(95.2,121.7) 
\Line(95.2,73.8)(95.8,73.8) 
\Line(95.8,71.8)(95.8,75.7) 
\Line(95.8,56.3)(97.1,56.3) 
\Line(96.5,55.0)(96.5,57.6) 
\Line(97.1,52.4)(97.7,52.4) 
\Line(97.1,51.1)(97.1,53.1) 
\Line(97.7,47.9)(98.3,47.9) 
\Line(98.3,47.2)(98.3,48.5) 
\Line(98.3,46.0)(99.6,46.0) 
\Line(99.0,45.3)(99.0,46.6) 
\Line(99.6,46.0)(100.2,46.0) 
\Line(99.6,45.3)(99.6,46.6) 
\Line(100.2,46.0)(100.8,46.0) 
\Line(100.8,45.3)(100.8,46.0) 
\Line(100.8,44.0)(101.5,44.0) 
\Line(101.5,44.0)(101.5,44.7) 
\Line(101.5,44.0)(102.7,44.0) 
\Line(102.1,43.4)(102.1,44.7) 
\Line(102.7,44.7)(103.3,44.7) 
\Line(102.7,44.0)(102.7,45.3) 
\Line(103.3,44.7)(104.0,44.7) 
\Line(104.0,44.0)(104.0,45.3) 
\Line(104.0,44.0)(105.2,44.0) 
\Line(104.6,44.0)(104.6,44.7) 
\Line(105.2,44.0)(105.8,44.0) 
\Line(105.2,43.4)(105.2,44.7) 
\Line(105.8,44.0)(106.5,44.0) 
\Line(105.8,43.4)(105.8,44.7) 
\Line(106.5,44.0)(107.1,44.0) 
\Line(107.1,43.4)(107.1,44.7) 
\Line(107.1,43.4)(108.4,43.4) 
\Line(107.7,43.4)(107.7,44.0) 
\Line(108.4,43.4)(109.0,43.4) 
\Line(108.4,42.7)(108.4,44.0) 
\Line(109.0,42.7)(109.6,42.7) 
\Line(109.6,42.1)(109.6,43.4) 
\Line(109.6,44.0)(110.9,44.0) 
\Line(110.2,42.7)(110.2,45.3) 
\Line(110.9,43.4)(111.5,43.4) 
\Line(110.9,42.7)(110.9,44.0) 
\Line(111.5,44.0)(112.1,44.0) 
\Line(111.5,43.4)(111.5,44.0) 
\Line(112.1,42.7)(112.7,42.7) 
\Line(112.7,42.1)(112.7,43.4) 
\Line(112.7,43.4)(114.0,43.4) 
\Line(113.4,42.7)(113.4,43.4) 
\Line(114.0,42.7)(114.6,42.7) 
\Line(114.0,42.7)(114.0,43.4) 
\Line(114.6,42.7)(115.2,42.7) 
\Line(115.2,42.1)(115.2,43.4) 
\Line(115.2,42.7)(115.9,42.7) 
\Line(115.9,42.1)(115.9,42.7) 
\Line(115.9,42.7)(117.1,42.7) 
\Line(116.5,42.1)(116.5,42.7) 
\Line(117.1,43.4)(117.7,43.4) 
\Line(117.1,42.7)(117.1,43.4) 
\Line(117.7,42.1)(118.4,42.1) 
\Line(118.4,41.4)(118.4,42.1) 
\Line(118.4,42.7)(119.6,42.7) 
\Line(119.0,42.1)(119.0,42.7) 
\Line(119.6,42.1)(120.3,42.1) 
\Line(119.6,42.1)(119.6,42.7) 
\Line(120.3,42.1)(120.9,42.1) 
\Line(120.9,42.1)(120.9,42.7) 
\Line(120.9,42.7)(121.5,42.7) 
\Line(121.5,42.1)(121.5,43.4) 
\Line(121.5,42.1)(122.8,42.1) 
\Line(122.1,42.1)(122.1,42.7) 
\Line(122.8,42.1)(123.4,42.1) 
\Line(122.8,41.4)(122.8,42.1) 
\Line(123.4,42.1)(124.0,42.1) 
\Line(124.0,41.4)(124.0,42.1) 
\Line(124.0,42.1)(125.3,42.1) 
\Line(124.6,42.1)(124.6,42.7) 
\Line(125.3,42.1)(125.9,42.1) 
\Line(125.3,41.4)(125.3,42.1) 
\Line(125.9,42.1)(126.5,42.1) 
\Line(125.9,42.1)(125.9,42.7) 
\Line(126.5,42.1)(127.1,42.1) 
\Line(127.1,41.4)(127.1,42.1) 
\Line(127.1,41.4)(128.4,41.4) 
\Line(127.8,41.4)(127.8,42.1) 
\Line(128.4,42.1)(129.0,42.1) 
\Line(128.4,41.4)(128.4,42.1) 
\Line(129.0,41.4)(129.6,41.4) 
\Line(129.6,40.8)(129.6,41.4) 
\Line(129.6,41.4)(130.9,41.4) 
\Line(130.3,40.8)(130.3,42.1) 
\Line(130.9,40.8)(131.5,40.8) 
\Line(130.9,40.8)(130.9,41.4) 
\Line(131.5,42.1)(132.2,42.1) 
\Line(131.5,42.1)(131.5,42.7) 
\Line(132.2,41.4)(132.8,41.4) 
\Line(132.8,40.8)(132.8,42.1) 
\Line(132.8,42.1)(134.0,42.1) 
\Line(133.4,42.1)(133.4,42.7) 
\Line(134.0,41.4)(134.7,41.4) 
\Line(134.0,40.8)(134.0,41.4) 
\Line(134.7,41.4)(135.3,41.4) 
\Line(135.3,41.4)(135.3,42.1) 
\Line(135.3,41.4)(135.9,41.4) 
\Line(135.9,41.4)(135.9,42.1) 
\Line(135.9,41.4)(137.2,41.4) 
\Line(136.5,40.8)(136.5,41.4) 
\Line(137.2,41.4)(137.8,41.4) 
\Line(137.2,40.8)(137.2,42.1) 
\Line(137.8,40.8)(138.4,40.8) 
\Line(138.4,40.8)(138.4,41.4) 
\Line(138.4,40.8)(139.7,40.8) 
\Line(139.0,40.1)(139.0,40.8) 
\Line(139.7,41.4)(140.3,41.4) 
\Line(139.7,40.8)(139.7,41.4) 
\Line(140.3,40.1)(140.9,40.1) 
\Line(140.9,40.1)(140.9,40.8) 
\Line(140.9,41.4)(141.5,41.4) 
\Line(141.5,41.4)(141.5,42.1) 
\Line(141.5,42.1)(142.8,42.1) 
\Line(142.2,41.4)(142.2,42.1) 
\Line(142.8,41.4)(143.4,41.4) 
\Line(142.8,40.8)(142.8,42.1) 
\Line(143.4,40.8)(144.1,40.8) 
\Line(144.1,40.8)(144.1,41.4) 
\Line(144.1,41.4)(145.3,41.4) 
\Line(144.7,40.8)(144.7,41.4) 
\Line(145.3,41.4)(145.9,41.4) 
\Line(145.3,40.8)(145.3,42.1) 
\Line(145.9,40.8)(146.6,40.8) 
\Line(145.9,40.1)(145.9,40.8) 
\Line(146.6,42.1)(147.2,42.1) 
\Line(147.2,41.4)(147.2,42.1) 
\Line(147.2,41.4)(148.4,41.4) 
\Line(147.8,41.4)(147.8,42.1) 
\Line(148.4,41.4)(149.1,41.4) 
\Line(148.4,40.8)(148.4,42.1) 
\Line(149.1,41.4)(149.7,41.4) 
\Line(149.7,40.8)(149.7,42.1) 
\Line(149.7,42.1)(150.9,42.1) 
\Line(150.3,41.4)(150.3,42.7) 
\Line(150.9,40.8)(151.6,40.8) 
\Line(150.9,40.8)(150.9,41.4) 
\Line(151.6,40.8)(152.2,40.8) 
\Line(151.6,40.8)(151.6,41.4) 
\Line(152.2,41.4)(152.8,41.4) 
\Line(152.8,40.8)(152.8,41.4) 
\Line(152.8,41.4)(154.1,41.4) 
\Line(153.4,40.8)(153.4,42.1) 
\Line(154.1,40.8)(154.7,40.8) 
\Line(154.1,40.8)(154.1,41.4) 
\Line(154.7,41.4)(155.3,41.4) 
\Line(155.3,41.4)(155.3,42.1) 
\Line(155.3,41.4)(155.9,41.4) 
\Line(155.9,40.8)(155.9,41.4) 
\Line(155.9,41.4)(157.2,41.4) 
\Line(156.6,40.8)(156.6,42.1) 
\Line(157.2,40.8)(157.8,40.8) 
\Line(157.2,40.1)(157.2,40.8) 
\Line(157.8,42.1)(158.5,42.1) 
\Line(158.5,41.4)(158.5,42.1) 
\Line(158.5,40.8)(159.7,40.8) 
\Line(159.1,40.1)(159.1,41.4) 
\Line(159.7,41.4)(160.3,41.4) 
\Line(159.7,40.8)(159.7,42.1) 
\Line(160.3,40.8)(161.0,40.8) 
\Line(161.0,40.1)(161.0,40.8) 
\Line(161.0,41.4)(161.6,41.4) 
\Line(161.6,40.8)(161.6,41.4) 
\Line(161.6,41.4)(162.8,41.4) 
\Line(162.2,40.8)(162.2,42.1) 
\Line(162.8,40.8)(163.5,40.8) 
\Line(162.8,40.1)(162.8,40.8) 
\Line(163.5,40.8)(164.1,40.8) 
\Line(164.1,40.8)(164.1,41.4) 
\Line(164.1,40.1)(165.3,40.1) 
\Line(164.7,40.1)(164.7,40.8) 
\Line(165.3,40.8)(166.0,40.8) 
\Line(165.3,40.1)(165.3,40.8) 
\Line(166.0,40.8)(166.6,40.8) 
\Line(166.0,40.8)(166.0,41.4) 
\Line(166.6,40.8)(167.2,40.8) 
\Line(167.2,40.8)(167.2,41.4) 
\Line(167.2,40.8)(168.5,40.8) 
\Line(167.8,40.8)(167.8,41.4) 
\Line(168.5,40.8)(169.1,40.8) 
\Line(168.5,40.1)(168.5,40.8) 
\Line(169.1,40.8)(169.7,40.8) 
\Line(169.7,40.1)(169.7,40.8) 
\Line(169.7,40.8)(171.0,40.8) 
\Line(170.4,40.8)(170.4,41.4) 
\Line(171.0,41.4)(171.6,41.4) 
\Line(171.0,41.4)(171.0,42.1) 
\Line(171.6,40.8)(172.2,40.8) 
\Line(171.6,40.1)(171.6,41.4) 
\Line(172.2,40.8)(172.9,40.8) 
\Line(172.9,40.1)(172.9,40.8) 
\Line(172.9,40.1)(174.1,40.1) 
\Line(173.5,40.1)(173.5,40.8) 
\Line(174.1,40.8)(174.7,40.8) 
\Line(174.1,40.1)(174.1,40.8) 
\Line(174.7,40.8)(175.4,40.8) 
\Line(175.4,40.1)(175.4,40.8) 
\Line(175.4,40.8)(176.0,40.8) 
\Line(176.0,40.1)(176.0,41.4) 
\Line(176.0,40.8)(177.2,40.8) 
\Line(176.6,40.1)(176.6,40.8) 
\Line(177.2,40.8)(177.9,40.8) 
\Line(177.2,40.8)(177.2,41.4) 
\Line(177.9,40.8)(178.5,40.8) 
\Line(178.5,40.1)(178.5,40.8) 
\Line(178.5,41.4)(179.7,41.4) 
\Line(179.1,40.8)(179.1,41.4) 
\Line(179.7,40.1)(180.4,40.1) 
\Line(179.7,40.1)(179.7,40.1) 
\Line(180.4,40.8)(181.0,40.8) 
\Line(181.0,40.1)(181.0,41.4) 
\Line(181.0,40.1)(181.6,40.1) 
\Line(181.6,40.1)(181.6,40.8) 
\Line(181.6,40.8)(182.9,40.8) 
\Line(182.3,40.1)(182.3,40.8) 
\Line(182.9,40.8)(183.5,40.8) 
\Line(182.9,40.1)(182.9,40.8) 
\Line(183.5,40.8)(184.1,40.8) 
\Line(184.1,40.8)(184.1,41.4) 
\Line(184.1,40.1)(185.4,40.1) 
\Line(184.8,40.1)(184.8,40.8) 
\Line(185.4,40.8)(186.0,40.8) 
\Line(185.4,40.1)(185.4,40.8) 
\Line(186.0,40.8)(186.6,40.8) 
\Line(186.0,40.1)(186.0,41.4) 
\Line(186.6,40.1)(187.3,40.1) 
\Line(187.3,40.1)(187.3,40.8) 
\Line(187.3,40.1)(188.5,40.1) 
\Line(187.9,40.1)(187.9,40.8) 
\Line(188.5,40.8)(189.1,40.8) 
\Line(188.5,40.1)(188.5,40.8) 
\Line(189.1,40.1)(189.8,40.1) 
\Line(189.8,40.1)(189.8,40.8) 
\Line(189.8,40.1)(191.0,40.1) 
\Line(190.4,40.1)(190.4,40.8) 
\Line(191.0,40.8)(191.6,40.8) 
\Line(191.0,40.1)(191.0,40.8) 
\Line(191.6,40.8)(192.3,40.8) 
\Line(191.6,40.8)(191.6,41.4) 
\Line(192.3,40.1)(192.9,40.1) 
\Line(192.9,40.1)(192.9,40.8) 
\Line(192.9,40.8)(194.2,40.8) 
\Line(193.5,40.1)(193.5,41.4) 
\Line(194.2,40.8)(194.8,40.8) 
\Line(194.2,40.1)(194.2,40.8) 
\Line(194.8,40.8)(195.4,40.8) 
\Line(195.4,40.1)(195.4,40.8) 
\Line(195.4,40.8)(196.0,40.8) 
\Line(196.0,40.1)(196.0,40.8) 
\Line(196.0,40.8)(197.3,40.8) 
\Line(196.7,40.1)(196.7,41.4) 
\Line(197.3,40.8)(197.9,40.8) 
\Line(197.3,40.1)(197.3,40.8) 
\Line(197.9,40.8)(198.5,40.8) 
\Line(198.5,40.8)(198.5,41.4) 
\Line(198.5,41.4)(199.8,41.4) 
\Line(199.2,40.8)(199.2,41.4) 
\Line(199.8,40.1)(200.4,40.1) 
\Line(199.8,40.1)(199.8,40.8) 
\Line(200.4,40.1)(201.0,40.1) 
\Line(201.0,40.1)(201.0,40.8) 
\Line(201.0,40.8)(201.7,40.8) 
\Line(201.7,40.8)(201.7,41.4) 
\Line(201.7,40.1)(202.9,40.1) 
\Line(202.3,40.1)(202.3,40.1) 
\Line(202.9,40.8)(203.5,40.8) 
\Line(202.9,40.8)(202.9,41.4) 
\Line(203.5,40.1)(204.2,40.1) 
\Line(204.2,39.5)(204.2,40.1) 
\Line(204.2,40.1)(205.4,40.1) 
\Line(204.8,39.5)(204.8,40.1) 
\Line(205.4,40.1)(206.1,40.1) 
\Line(205.4,39.5)(205.4,40.1) 
\Line(206.1,40.8)(206.7,40.8) 
\Line(206.1,40.1)(206.1,40.8) 
\Line(206.7,40.1)(207.3,40.1) 
\Line(207.3,40.1)(207.3,40.1) 
\Line(207.3,40.8)(208.6,40.8) 
\Line(207.9,40.1)(207.9,40.8) 
\Line(208.6,40.1)(209.2,40.1) 
\Line(208.6,40.1)(208.6,40.8) 
\Line(209.2,40.8)(209.8,40.8) 
\Line(209.8,40.1)(209.8,40.8) 
\Line(209.8,40.8)(211.1,40.8) 
\Line(210.4,40.1)(210.4,40.8) 
\Line(211.1,40.8)(211.7,40.8) 
\Line(211.1,40.8)(211.1,41.4) 
\Line(211.7,40.8)(212.3,40.8) 
\Line(211.7,40.1)(211.7,40.8) 
\Line(212.3,40.8)(212.9,40.8) 
\Line(212.9,40.1)(212.9,40.8) 
\Line(212.9,40.1)(214.2,40.1) 
\Line(213.6,39.5)(213.6,40.1) 
\Line(214.2,40.1)(214.8,40.1) 
\Line(214.2,39.5)(214.2,40.1) 
\Line(214.8,40.8)(215.4,40.8) 
\Line(215.4,40.1)(215.4,40.8) 
\Line(215.4,40.8)(216.1,40.8) 
\Line(216.1,40.1)(216.1,40.8) 
\Line(216.1,40.1)(217.3,40.1) 
\Line(216.7,40.1)(216.7,40.8) 
\Line(217.3,40.1)(218.0,40.1) 
\Line(217.3,40.1)(217.3,40.1) 
\Line(218.0,40.1)(218.6,40.1) 
\Line(218.6,40.1)(218.6,40.8) 
\Line(218.6,40.1)(219.8,40.1) 
\Line(219.2,40.1)(219.2,40.8) 
\Line(219.8,40.8)(220.5,40.8) 
\Line(219.8,40.1)(219.8,40.8) 
\Line(220.5,40.1)(221.1,40.1) 
\Line(221.1,40.1)(221.1,40.8) 
\Line(221.1,40.8)(221.7,40.8) 
\Line(221.7,40.1)(221.7,40.8) 
\Line(221.7,40.1)(223.0,40.1) 
\Line(222.3,40.1)(222.3,40.1) 
\Line(223.0,40.1)(223.6,40.1) 
\Line(223.0,40.1)(223.0,40.8) 
\Line(223.6,40.8)(224.2,40.8) 
\Line(224.2,40.1)(224.2,40.8) 
\Line(224.2,40.1)(225.5,40.1) 
\Line(224.8,40.1)(224.8,40.8) 
\Line(225.5,40.1)(226.1,40.1) 
\Line(225.5,40.1)(225.5,40.8) 
\Line(226.1,40.8)(226.7,40.8) 
\Line(226.1,40.1)(226.1,40.8) 
\Line(226.7,40.8)(227.3,40.8) 
\Line(227.3,40.1)(227.3,40.8) 
\Line(227.3,40.1)(228.6,40.1) 
\Line(228.0,39.5)(228.0,40.1) 
\Line(228.6,40.8)(229.2,40.8) 
\Line(228.6,40.1)(228.6,40.8) 
\Line(229.2,40.1)(229.9,40.1) 
\Line(229.9,40.1)(229.9,40.8) 
\Line(229.9,40.8)(231.1,40.8) 
\Line(230.5,40.1)(230.5,40.8) 
\Line(231.1,40.1)(231.7,40.1) 
\Line(231.1,39.5)(231.1,40.1) 
\Line(231.7,40.8)(232.4,40.8) 
\Line(231.7,40.1)(231.7,41.4) 
\Line(232.4,40.1)(233.0,40.1) 
\Line(233.0,40.1)(233.0,40.8) 
\Line(233.0,40.1)(234.2,40.1) 
\Line(233.6,39.5)(233.6,40.1) 
\Line(234.2,40.1)(234.9,40.1) 
\Line(234.2,40.1)(234.2,40.1) 
\Line(234.9,40.8)(235.5,40.8) 
\Line(235.5,40.1)(235.5,40.8) 
\Line(235.5,40.1)(236.1,40.1) 
\Line(236.1,39.5)(236.1,40.1) 
\Line(236.1,40.1)(237.4,40.1) 
\Line(236.7,39.5)(236.7,40.1) 
\Line(237.4,39.5)(238.0,39.5) 
\Line(237.4,39.5)(237.4,39.5) 
\Line(238.0,40.1)(238.6,40.1) 
\Line(238.6,40.1)(238.6,40.8) 
\Line(238.6,40.8)(239.9,40.8) 
\Line(239.2,40.1)(239.2,41.4) 
\Line(239.9,40.1)(240.5,40.1) 
\Line(239.9,40.1)(239.9,40.1) 
\Line(240.5,40.8)(241.1,40.8) 
\Line(241.1,40.1)(241.1,40.8) 
\Line(241.1,40.1)(241.8,40.1) 
\Line(241.8,39.5)(241.8,40.1) 
\Line(241.8,40.1)(243.0,40.1) 
\Line(242.4,39.5)(242.4,40.1) 
\Line(243.0,40.1)(243.6,40.1) 
\Line(243.0,40.1)(243.0,40.8) 
\Line(243.6,39.5)(244.3,39.5) 
\Line(244.3,39.5)(244.3,40.1) 
\Line(244.3,40.1)(245.5,40.1) 
\Line(244.9,40.1)(244.9,40.8) 
\Line(245.5,40.1)(246.1,40.1) 
\Line(245.5,40.1)(245.5,40.8) 
\Line(246.1,39.5)(246.8,39.5) 
\Line(246.1,39.5)(246.1,40.1) 
\Line(246.8,40.8)(247.4,40.8) 
\Line(247.4,40.1)(247.4,40.8) 
\Line(247.4,40.1)(248.6,40.1) 
\Line(248.0,40.1)(248.0,40.1) 
\Line(248.6,40.1)(249.3,40.1) 
\Line(248.6,40.1)(248.6,40.1) 
\Line(249.3,40.1)(249.9,40.1) 
\Line(249.9,40.1)(249.9,40.8) 
\Line(249.9,40.1)(251.1,40.1) 
\Line(250.5,40.1)(250.5,40.1) 
\Line(251.1,40.1)(251.8,40.1) 
\Line(251.1,40.1)(251.1,40.1) 
\Line(251.8,40.1)(252.4,40.1) 
\Line(251.8,39.5)(251.8,40.1) 
\Line(252.4,39.5)(253.0,39.5) 
\Line(253.0,39.5)(253.0,40.1) 
\Line(253.0,40.1)(254.3,40.1) 
\Line(253.7,40.1)(253.7,40.8) 
\Line(254.3,40.1)(254.9,40.1) 
\Line(254.3,39.5)(254.3,40.1) 
\Line(254.9,39.5)(255.5,39.5) 
\Line(255.5,39.5)(255.5,40.1) 
\Line(255.5,40.1)(256.2,40.1) 
\Line(256.2,40.1)(256.2,40.8) 
\Line(256.2,40.1)(257.4,40.1) 
\Line(256.8,39.5)(256.8,40.1) 
\Line(257.4,40.8)(258.0,40.8) 
\Line(257.4,40.1)(257.4,40.8) 
\Line(258.0,39.5)(258.7,39.5) 
\Line(258.7,39.5)(258.7,40.1) 
\Line(258.7,40.1)(259.9,40.1) 
\Line(259.3,39.5)(259.3,40.1) 
\Line(259.9,39.5)(260.5,39.5) 
\Line(259.9,39.5)(259.9,40.1) 
\Line(260.5,40.1)(261.2,40.1) 
\Line(261.2,40.1)(261.2,40.8) 
\Line(261.2,40.1)(261.8,40.1) 
\Line(261.8,40.1)(261.8,40.1) 
\Line(261.8,40.1)(263.0,40.1) 
\Line(262.4,39.5)(262.4,40.1) 
\Line(263.0,39.5)(263.7,39.5) 
\Line(263.0,39.5)(263.0,40.1) 
\Line(263.7,40.1)(264.3,40.1) 
\Line(264.3,39.5)(264.3,40.1) 
\Line(264.3,39.5)(265.6,39.5) 
\Line(264.9,39.5)(264.9,40.1) 
\Line(265.6,39.5)(266.2,39.5) 
\Line(265.6,39.5)(265.6,40.1) 
\Line(266.2,40.1)(266.8,40.1) 
\Line(266.2,39.5)(266.2,40.1) 
\Line(266.8,39.5)(267.4,39.5) 
\Line(267.4,39.5)(267.4,40.1) 
\Line(267.4,40.1)(268.7,40.1) 
\Line(268.1,40.1)(268.1,40.8) 
\Line(268.7,40.1)(269.3,40.1) 
\Line(268.7,39.5)(268.7,40.1) 
\Line(269.3,40.1)(269.9,40.1) 
\Line(269.9,39.5)(269.9,40.1) 
\Line(269.9,39.5)(271.2,39.5) 
\Line(270.6,39.5)(270.6,40.1) 
\Line(271.2,40.1)(271.8,40.1) 
\Line(271.2,40.1)(271.2,40.1) 
\Line(271.8,40.1)(272.4,40.1) 
\Line(271.8,40.1)(271.8,40.1) 
\Line(272.4,40.1)(273.1,40.1) 
\Line(273.1,39.5)(273.1,40.1) 
\Line(273.1,40.1)(274.3,40.1) 
\Line(273.7,39.5)(273.7,40.1) 
\Line(274.3,39.5)(274.9,39.5) 
\Line(274.3,39.5)(274.3,40.1) 
\Line(274.9,40.1)(275.6,40.1) 
\Line(275.6,40.1)(275.6,40.8) 
\Line(275.6,40.1)(276.2,40.1) 
\Line(276.2,40.1)(276.2,40.8) 
\Line(276.2,39.5)(277.5,39.5) 
\Line(276.8,39.5)(276.8,40.1) 
\Line(277.5,40.1)(278.1,40.1) 
\Line(277.5,40.1)(277.5,40.8) 
\Line(278.1,39.5)(278.7,39.5) 
\Line(278.7,39.5)(278.7,40.1) 
\Line(278.7,40.8)(280.0,40.8) 
\Line(279.3,40.1)(279.3,40.8) 
\Line(280.0,40.1)(280.6,40.1) 
\Line(280.0,39.5)(280.0,40.1) 
\Line(280.6,39.5)(281.2,39.5) 
\Line(281.2,39.5)(281.2,40.1) 
\Line(281.2,40.1)(281.8,40.1) 
\Line(281.8,39.5)(281.8,40.1) 
\Line(281.8,40.1)(283.1,40.1) 
\Line(282.5,39.5)(282.5,40.1) 
\Line(283.1,40.1)(283.7,40.1) 
\Line(283.1,39.5)(283.1,40.1) 
\Line(283.7,40.1)(284.3,40.1) 
\Line(284.3,40.1)(284.3,40.8) 
\Line(284.3,40.1)(285.6,40.1) 
\Line(285.0,40.1)(285.0,40.8) 
\Line(285.6,40.1)(286.2,40.1) 
\Line(285.6,39.5)(285.6,40.1) 
\Line(286.2,39.5)(286.8,39.5) 
\Line(286.2,39.5)(286.2,40.1) 
\Line(286.8,40.1)(287.5,40.1) 
\Line(287.5,40.1)(287.5,40.1) 
\Line(287.5,39.5)(288.7,39.5) 
\Line(288.1,39.5)(288.1,40.1) 
\Line(288.7,39.5)(289.4,39.5) 
\Line(288.7,39.5)(288.7,40.1) 
\Line(289.4,39.5)(290.0,39.5) 
\Line(290.0,39.5)(290.0,39.5) 
\Line(290.0,40.1)(291.2,40.1) 
\Line(290.6,39.5)(290.6,40.1) 
\end{picture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `\documentstyle[axodraw]{article}` try using `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{axodraw}`

Comment: same problem it only writes the axis names but there is no corresponding function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` and *not* `pdflatex` or `xelatex`! `axodraw` needs the `dvips` driver.

[image]

However, you should use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{axodraw}
\begin{document}
....
```

the `\documentstyle` command is really outdated.

Comment: thank you very much. however i couldn't include it in the article that im writing it does not open it as dvi or ps and it does not draw the graph in pdf.

Comment: "does not draw"  is not a useful description of the problem. If I use `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` I get a proper pdf output

Comment: well i think i dont know how to do latex->dvips->ps2pdf im using texmaker and it has only 2 steps of compilation i tried firs latex->dvi then (dvi->ps)->pdf. the first pattern gave me the article but graph had no dots or lines on it completely empty and the second pattern gave me an error

Comment: looks like that you do not have GhostScript installed. You can run all commands from the terminal. Then it is easier to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I followed steps below
latex myfile.tex
dvips myfile.dvi
ps2pdf myfile.ps

in terminal this time i got a ps file that includes the graph as you send but thistime other pages are dammaged it didnt showed the title page at all.

Comment: you cannot use pdf or jpeg images when using axodraw. Convert it to eps.